# Add newly-created List to Sharepoint left navigation's 'Recent'

Tags: navigation, sharepoint-2013

I wonder if there's a way to add a navigation link to Sharepoint's left navigation's 'Recent' programmatically? It only shows up when I create a list on the web interface

**UPDATE**: It turns out that there's no way to add a link to the **Recent** section of left navigation programmatically. So I just fixed it there on left navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the classes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.quicklaunch.aspx. There will be a way to add links to the quick launch (this is the 'official' name of the navigation on the left) through using web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.

web.Navigation.AddToQuickLaunch(x,x);

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms427791%28v=office.14%29.aspx